# CLIPS: modify-instance does not trigger pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, rules, rule-engine, clips

Having a file test.clp:

```
(defclass TestClass (is-a USER)
    (role concrete)
    (pattern-match reactive)
    (slot value)
    (slot threshold))


(definstances TestObjects 
    (Test of TestClass
    (value 0)
    (threshold 3)))

(defrule above-threshold
    ?test <- (object (is-a TestClass))
    (test (> (send ?test get-value) (send ?test get-threshold)))
    =>
    (printout t "*** Above threshold!! ***" crlf)
    (refresh below-threshold))

(defrule below-threshold
    ?test <- (object (is-a TestClass))
    (test (> (send ?test get-value) (send ?test get-threshold)))
    =>
    (printout t "*** Back to normal ***" crlf)
    (refresh above-threshold))
```

I load the file and:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      below-threshold: [Test]
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run) 
*** Back to normal ***
CLIPS> (modify-instance [Test] (value 8))
TRUE
CLIPS> (agenda)
CLIPS>
```

The agenda does not show any active rule. I would expect the change (modify-instance) for value to 8 would trigger pattern matching and rule "above-threshold" would be selected for running and put in the agenda. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section 5.4.1.7, Pattern-Matching with Object Patterns, of the Basic Programming Guide:

> When an instance is created or deleted, all patterns applicable to
>   that object are updated. However, when a slot is changed, only those
>   patterns that explicitly match on that slot are affected.

So modify the rules to explicitly match the slots you want to trigger pattern matching:

```
(defrule above-threshold
    ?test <- (object (is-a TestClass)
                     (value ?value)
                     (threshold ?threshold))
    (test (> ?value ?threshold))
    =>
    (printout t "*** Above threshold!! ***" crlf)
    (refresh below-threshold))

(defrule below-threshold
    ?test <- (object (is-a TestClass)
                     (value ?value)
                     (threshold ?threshold))
    (test (< ?value ?threshold))
    =>
    (printout t "*** Back to normal ***" crlf)
    (refresh above-threshold))
```